# TortoiseHG automatically deinstalled on software update, ubuntu software centre now refuse to re-install (U-14.04)

Tags: 14.04, mercurial

details:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mercurial
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mercurial is already the newest version.
mercurial set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get install tortoisehg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tortoisehg : Depends: mercurial (< 2.9~) but 3.3.2-1ppa2~trusty1 is to be installed
              Recommends: python-iniparse but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

any ideas/hints to get tortoisehg back in func?

thank you very much for amazingly well described troubleshooting on [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) however even after applying all major prescriptions with cleaning the databasei still get the same message.

One thing did happen: adding all sources did trigger update of many other packages - thanks for that

will research deeper

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: if you're getting any more errors try to disable duplicated PPAs/Sources that have the same packages it's also the problem.

Comment: no other errors, I installed manually required python module (INI files), tha has fixed py dependancy, now pondering demoting hg to v.2.9

Comment: did have & removed duplicates. not fixed. will try to disable all ppa's

Comment: after you disable conflicting ppas you have to run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. ; retry install - still the same.

Comment: everything seems ok now what's the problem then? if `dist-upgrade` shows `0` to all then everything is ok with distro. Other issues might be only in PPAs that you have added if you can't install smth from that ppa.

Comment: You have to remove the mercurial ppa and regress the packages to a version that tortoise supports (less than 2.9).

Comment: also tried: remove tortoisehg ppa stable and add releases ppa instead. tried with enabled each one at a time. no go. Strating to believe this is tortoise bug. will wait & research more. thank you a lot JohnnyEnglish

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

1. removed/disabled duplicates/all mercurial & tortoisehg ppa's from software update app.
2. apt clean & update (following first hint & comments)
3. installed python module for .ini files (useful to me anyhow)
4. uninstalled existing mercurial 3.x using synaptic package manager
5. installed tortoisehg from ubuntu software center (dependances autoselected)

steps 1,2 & 3 perhaps not necessary but recommended

tortoisehg now working, repos ok - readable/functional

post install:

```
$ hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.0.1)
```

rerun software update, it claims no new updates available, will see how it'll behave on next software updates in future

credits to: dadexix86 & JohnnyEnglish